# how to save and load a number (integer) using CloudKit (swift)

Tags: swift, integer, int, cloudkit

I am creating an app that needs to save a counter variable (which is an integer) into the cloud when the app exits, then loads the counter when the app becomes active. Ive never used CloudKit before could someone simplify how i could do this using swift? many of the examples I've tried to replicate are too complex for what I am trying to achieve.

Note:  Before anyone mentions it , I know there are other ways to achieve this but I want to do it using CloudKit.

Also, I already understand how appDelegate transitions work so i don't need help with that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CloudKit: Ok lets do some planning and get out assumptions agreed.

1. You need to check the network is up and reachable
2. You need check said user is logged into the cloud

Unclear as to the nature of what your really want to do here beyond writing a noddy method; lets assuming you want something a bit more.

3. You save your integer using cloud kit, ensuring any errors that come thru are handled. What sort of errors. Here a list for you.

`enum CKErrorCode : Int {
    case InternalError
    case PartialFailure
    case NetworkUnavailable
    case NetworkFailure
    case BadContainer
    case ServiceUnavailable
    case RequestRateLimited
    case MissingEntitlement
    case NotAuthenticated
    case PermissionFailure
    case UnknownItem
    case InvalidArguments
    case ResultsTruncated
    case ServerRecordChanged
    case ServerRejectedRequest
    case AssetFileNotFound
    case AssetFileModified
    case IncompatibleVersion
    case ConstraintViolation
    case OperationCancelled
    case ChangeTokenExpired
    case BatchRequestFailed
    case ZoneBusy
    case BadDatabase
    case QuotaExceeded
    case ZoneNotFound
    case LimitExceeded
    case UserDeletedZone
}`

4. You might want to read the thing back to check it even if you don't get any errors, it is a very important integer. You need to handle these errors if you do that too.

OK, you saved it; what about next time. Ok its the same palaver, network, cloud kit, read, deal with errors etc etc.

If your still here, well done. Here the code just to save a record.

```
func save2Cloud(yourInt:Int) {

    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.blah")
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase

    let newRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "BlahBlah")
    newRecord.setObject(yourInt, forKey: "theInt")

    var localChanges:[CKRecord] = []
    var recordIDsToDelete:[CKRecord] = []

    localChanges.append(newRecord)

    let saveRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: localChanges, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
    saveRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock =  { record, error in
        if error != nil {
            self.showAlert(message: error!.localizedDescription)
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // give the UI a all good sign for that record
            }
    }
    saveRecordsOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
        if error != nil {
            self.showAlert(message: error!.localizedDescription)
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // give the UI a all good sign for all records
            }
        }
    }
    saveRecordsOperation.qualityOfService = .Background
    publicDB.addOperation(saveRecordsOperation)
}
```

And here the code to read it back.

```
var readerOperation: CKQueryOperation!

func read4Cloud(theLink: String, theCount: Int) {
    var starCount:Int = 0
    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.blah")
    let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "BlahBlah", predicate: predicate)

    readerOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    readerOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
        let YourInt = record["theInt"] as! Int
    }

    readerOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {(cursor, error) in
    if error != nil {
            // oh dingbats, you need to check for one of those errors
    } else {
       // got it
    }
    }
    readerOperation.qualityOfService = .Background
    publicDB.addOperation(readerOperation)
}
```

But wait Matt, this is going to save a new record everytime, and read back multiple Ints when you re-open. No this solution needs some more work; and I haven't done the network or the cloud check or any of the errors... :\

Disclaimer; I edited this code in SO, it may not compile cleanly :)

Answer (score 0):

Matt, the reason you should do this another way is cause it is far simpler and will almost certainly be more reliable than cloud kit.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(yourInt, forKey: "blah")
```

Your got these options in swift ...

```
func setBool(value: Bool, forKey defaultName: String)
func setInteger(value: Int, forKey defaultName: String)
func setFloat(value: Float, forKey defaultName: String)
func setDouble(value: Double, forKey defaultName: String)
func setObject(value: AnyObject?, forKey defaultName: String)
func setURL(url: NSURL, forKey defaultName: String)
```

To fetch the value the next time

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let yourInt = defaults.integerForKey("blah")
{
    print(yourInt)
}
```

You got a few more methods to get them back

```
func boolForKey(defaultName: String) -> Bool
func integerForKey(defaultName: String) -> Int
func floatForKey(defaultName: String) -> Float
func doubleForKey(defaultName: String) -> Double
func objectForKey(defaultName: String) -> AnyObject?
func URLForKey(defaultName: String) -> NSURL?
func dataForKey(defaultName: String) -> NSData?
func stringForKey(defaultName: String) -> String?
func stringArrayForKey(defaultName: String) -> [AnyObject]?
func arrayForKey(defaultName: String) -> [AnyObject]?
func dictionaryForKey(defaultName: String) -> [NSObject : AnyObject]?
```

And that is it; but wait, you want to use cloud kit... let me give you a second answer after I post this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to do it in Cloud Kit. Feel free to post a comment suggesting that `NSUserDefaults` is probably a better idea.